# Text displayed in wrong charset on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I did a quick search and found no fitting post/question just yet.

Apparently, there is something going wrong on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

[image]

As you can see, some characters between the initials and the company name have gone rogue.

Just to confirm, I' ve opened http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ and http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de on the following browsers:

- Google Chrome 33.0.1750.154
- Firefox 15.0.1 / 16.0.1
- Internet Explorer 11

Kind regards

Comment: W00t, and it's not a client-side encoding issue as the `...` ellipses are displayed correctly (the page is encoded to UTF-8).

Comment: Looks like a doubly-encoded [U+FFFD codepoint](http://codepoints.net/U+fffd) (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER), which may indicate even more has gone wrong along the way.

Comment: I noticed it earlier today. Someone's working on it.

Comment: @Juice and you really thought nobody will notice, eh? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sometimes I'm shocked at the things people point out.

Comment: @Juice of course, Quality Assurance 2.0!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now removed the weird character, no idea how that slipped in there...